# Customize TOC (colors) of classicthesis

Tags: table-of-contents, color, classicthesis

I am using `classicthesis` as a template for my thesis. The thing is that I want to put a different color for the chapters on the table of contents.
Example:

> CONTENTS
>
> 1 Introduction (on color red)
>
> 1.1 Motive
>
> 1.2 Anything

Thanks! I hope you can help me.

Comment: What exactly should receive color: just the chapter titles? the titles and chapter numbers? the tiles, chapter number and page numbers? Which document class are you using? Which options for `classicthesis` are you using? Please add that information to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `classicthesis` internally uses the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package, you can redefine `\cftchapfont` and `\cftchappagefont` to add the desired color; a little example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont\color{red}}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC:

[image]

Comment: @Sego You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.